# bundle exec rails always returns rails documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

When running

```
bundle exec rails c
```

or any other rails command like server or runner rails always returns the output of "rails help"

The same installation runs successfully on an other server.

Comment: are you inside the newly created app directory?, please check. if not then try `cd` into your app

Comment: "The same installation" Where same means what? Which version of Ruby, Rails? What about your bin folder?

Comment: Yes, i'm inside the app directory. It isn't newly created - it's copied from an other place.

Comment: Ruby 2.3, Rails 4.2 bin folder includes the follwofing files: bourbon, bundle, bundler, coderay, erubis, guard, _guard-core, listen, nokogiri, pry, rackup, rails, rake, rdoc, ri, sass, sass-convert, scss, sdoc, sdoc-merge, setup, spring, sprockets, thin, thor, tilt, unicorn, unicorn_rails, whenever, wheneverize, yard, yardoc, yri

Comment: Try to run ```rake rails:update:bin``` to update bin/bundle, bin/rails, and bin/rake.

Comment: @PascalTurbo are you using `rvm` to manage your ruby installs?

Comment: rake rails:update:bin didn't help

Comment: I'm using a "rpm installation" of ruby - not rvm

Answer (score 0):

**This is assuming you use `rvm`.**

The fact that you copied it from another server probably means you are using the ruby gemset that came with that installation. This might be missing on your new system.

In your appfolder, run: `rvm gemset list` to see which gemset you are using. Equally you could look for `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-gemset` and `.ruby-version` in the root folder of your app.

`rvmrc` is outdated but these files should contain ruby version and gemset name that is being used by the app.

Switch to that gemset with:

`rvm gemset use <gemset name>`

or if it doesn't exist use:

`rvm use --create <ruby version>@<gemset name>`

Then to install all gems run:

`bundle install`